# Drawing Smooth Curves in Java Graphics

Tags: java, graphics

I am trying to draw smooth, bezier-type curves to fit a set of data I have in order to plot it in a java graphics drawing. 
Below is the code I am currently using to plot. It is plotting the points just fine, except that the curves have sharp edges and sometimes have small fractures in them. Is there a better way that I can make a smooth, fitted curve using java graphics?

```
int numProfiles = speedList.size();
        int lenOfList;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Creating a new general path");

        //BasicStroke boldStroke = new BasicStroke(.3f);
        //((Graphics2D)g).setStroke(boldStroke);
        for (int i=0; i<numProfiles; i++){
            GeneralPath gp = new GeneralPath();
            g.setColor(colors[i]);
            lenOfList = speedList.get(i).length;
            if (lenOfList < 3) {
                double xPlotVal1 = xMarginLeft + (((speedList.get(i)[0].getVal() - xMin) / (xMax - xMin)) * width);
                double yPlotVal1 = yMarginTopAxisTop + (((depthList.get(i)[0].getVal() - yMin) / (yMax - yMin)) * height);

                double xPlotVal2 = xMarginLeft + (((speedList.get(i)[1].getVal() - xMin) / (xMax - xMin)) * width);
                double yPlotVal2 = yMarginTopAxisTop + (((depthList.get(i)[1].getVal() - yMin) / (yMax - yMin)) * height);

                g.drawLine((int) xPlotVal1, (int) yPlotVal1, (int) xPlotVal2, (int) yPlotVal2);

            } else {
                System.out.println("More than 2 pts");
                for (int j = 0; j < (lenOfList - 2); j++) {

                    double xPlotVal1 = xMarginLeft + (((speedList.get(i)[j].getVal() - xMin) / (xMax - xMin)) * width);
                    double yPlotVal1 = yMarginTopAxisTop + (((depthList.get(i)[j].getVal() - yMin) / (yMax - yMin)) * height);

                    double xPlotVal2 = xMarginLeft + (((speedList.get(i)[j + 1].getVal() - xMin) / (xMax - xMin)) * width);
                    double yPlotVal2 = yMarginTopAxisTop + (((depthList.get(i)[j + 1].getVal() - yMin) / (yMax - yMin)) * height);

                    double xPlotVal3 = xMarginLeft + (((speedList.get(i)[j + 2].getVal() - xMin) / (xMax - xMin)) * width);
                    double yPlotVal3 = yMarginTopAxisTop + (((depthList.get(i)[j + 2].getVal() - yMin) / (yMax - yMin)) * height);
                    gp.moveTo(xPlotVal1, yPlotVal1);

                    if (j==0) gp.moveTo(xPlotVal1, yPlotVal1);
                    //  gp.moveTo(xPlotVal1, yPlotVal1);
                    gp.curveTo(xPlotVal1, yPlotVal1, xPlotVal2, yPlotVal2,
                            xPlotVal3, yPlotVal3);

                }
                ((Graphics2D) g).draw(gp);
            }
        }
```

Here is a picture of what it's drawing:
[image]

//June 26, 2012 at 7:34AM
//Here is the updated code after I added the rendering hint

```
    // the profiles
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    int numProfiles = speedList.size();
    int lenOfList;
    for (int i=0; i<numProfiles; i++){
        GeneralPath gp = new GeneralPath();
        g2d.setColor(colors[i]);

        lenOfList = speedList.get(i).length;
        if (lenOfList < 3) {
            double xPlotVal1 = xMarginLeft + (((speedList.get(i)[0].getVal() - xMin) / (xMax - xMin)) * width);
            double yPlotVal1 = yMarginTopAxisTop + (((depthList.get(i)[0].getVal() - yMin) / (yMax - yMin)) * height);

            double xPlotVal2 = xMarginLeft + (((speedList.get(i)[1].getVal() - xMin) / (xMax - xMin)) * width);
            double yPlotVal2 = yMarginTopAxisTop + (((depthList.get(i)[1].getVal() - yMin) / (yMax - yMin)) * height);

            g2d.drawLine((int) xPlotVal1, (int) yPlotVal1, (int) xPlotVal2, (int) yPlotVal2);

        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < (lenOfList - 2); j++) {

                double xPlotVal1 = xMarginLeft + (((speedList.get(i)[j].getVal() - xMin) / (xMax - xMin)) * width);
                double yPlotVal1 = yMarginTopAxisTop + (((depthList.get(i)[j].getVal() - yMin) / (yMax - yMin)) * height);

                double xPlotVal2 = xMarginLeft + (((speedList.get(i)[j + 1].getVal() - xMin) / (xMax - xMin)) * width);
                double yPlotVal2 = yMarginTopAxisTop + (((depthList.get(i)[j + 1].getVal() - yMin) / (yMax - yMin)) * height);

                double xPlotVal3 = xMarginLeft + (((speedList.get(i)[j + 2].getVal() - xMin) / (xMax - xMin)) * width);
                double yPlotVal3 = yMarginTopAxisTop + (((depthList.get(i)[j + 2].getVal() - yMin) / (yMax - yMin)) * height);
                gp.moveTo(xPlotVal1, yPlotVal1);

                if (j==0) gp.moveTo(xPlotVal1, yPlotVal1);      //only move at the begining of the curve drawing
                //  gp.moveTo(xPlotVal1, yPlotVal1);
                gp.curveTo(xPlotVal1, yPlotVal1, xPlotVal2, yPlotVal2,
                        xPlotVal3, yPlotVal3);

            }
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
             g2d.draw(gp);
        }
    }
```

Here is the newest picture. I am not sure why it's making my background grid lines disappear. I plot the grid lines after I plot the colored profiles. 
[image]

Comment: How do I do that? I'm pretty new to Stack Overflow, so I don't quite know how it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enable antaliasing for Graphics2D object.

Do it like this

```
Graphics graphics = ...
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;

g2d.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

// You can also enable antialiasing for text:

g2d.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

Do this before drawing anything using the `graphics` object.

Also see the [RenderingHints javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html).

Comment: Hmm. I tried the Rendering Hint code and it is still drawing the same picture.

Comment: Post the updated code, perhaps your enabling the hints too late, or on the wrong object. And post your java version too.

Comment: Ok, just posted the updated version in my original post below the first try at the code.

Comment: Well, I can see the difference on the new image - the lines are slightly smoother. As to the gridlines - they are visible, but are really faint, you may want to disable anti-aliasing for them (using `setRenderingHint(KEY_ANTIALIASING, VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF)`.

Comment: Okay, awesome. The grid lines are back. The curves are smoother--but there is still that sharp corner with the pink one and the hairline split in the green one.

Comment: I'd say, that's because of how your path is build. It just contains those points.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Graphics2D` with the antialising:

```
 Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
 g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
     RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
 //...
 g2.draw(gp);
```